# Регулярное выражение для выборки адреса сайта

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
<table class='tbl5' cellspacing="1">
<tr><td class="th2">N</td><td class="th2">Domain</td><td class="th2">Removal date domain</td></tr>
<tr><td class="td2">1</td><td class="td2">domen.com.ua</td><td class="td2">2020-01-21 18:09:05+02</td></tr>
<tr><td class="td2">2</td><td class="td2">domen.com.ua</td><td class="td2">2020-01-21 18:09:05+02</td></tr>
.....
</table>
<br/>
```

Как из него выбрать домены? Сколько не пытался сделать регулярное выражение, не получалось. И, если я правильно думаю, то делать это надо через `preg_replace()`?

Comment: Нет, для этого используются функции `preg_match()` / `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: Для парсинга html используются xml-парсеры, а не регэксп-костыли.

Comment: Можете попробовать библиотеку https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PHP есть класс [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) для парсинга XML и HTML документов. Правда *(если не ошибаюсь)*, его возможности не столь велики, и вероятно понадобится дописывать уточняющие условия, например:

```
$html =<<<HTML
<table class='tbl5' cellspacing="1">
<tr><td class="th2">N</td><td class="th2">Domain</td><td class="th2">Removal date domain</td></tr>
<tr><td class="td2">1</td><td class="td2">domen.com.ua</td><td class="td2">2020-01-21 18:09:05+02</td></tr>
<tr><td class="td2">2</td><td class="td2">domen.com.ua</td><td class="td2">2020-01-21 18:09:05+02</td></tr>
.....
</table>
<br/>
HTML;

$domains = [];

$doc = new DOMDocument;

if ($doc->loadHTML($html)) {
    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('td') as $tag) {
        if ($tag->getAttribute('class') == 'td2') {
            strpos($tag->textContent, '.') === false ?: $domains[] = $tag->textContent;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($domains);
```

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(12) "domen.com.ua"
  [1]=> string(12) "domen.com.ua"
}
```

Comment: Для моих нужд вариант дом подходит идеально и все упрощает. Остальное смогу дописать.